# Updating Elasticsearch Query parameter in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am querying elasticsearch in python. I want to change a parameter 'default operator' in case query returns zero values.
Here's my code:

> ```
> default_operator = "and"
> if searchfields is not None:
>     if query is not None and query != '':
>         queries.append(Q("simple_query_string", query=query, default_operator= default_operator,
>                         flags="PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE", fields=searchfields))
> ```

There is a long code after this in which different filters are being made and added to the query. But here's the code where I am trying to change the default operator:

> ```
> res = s.execute()
> if res["hits"]["total"]["value"] == 0:
>    default_operator = "or"
>    print("Query with default operator OR: ", str(queries))
>    res = s.execute()
> else:
>   pass
> ```

But it is not changing the default operator. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you recreate the query itself with new value of `default_operator`?

Comment: That's the question that how to update a query without having to recreate it all together?

Comment: The same code, `Q("simple_query_string", query=query, default_operator= default_operator, flags="PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE", fields=searchfields)`